How to Save PDF Annotations to PDF Using Android PdfViewer - Kotlin
Edit: Our app is not open source and we have explored some of the paid license options, such as iText, but the pricing is out of our range.
I am using barteksc.pdfviewer (https://github.com/DImuthuUpe/AndroidPdfViewer) to load a PDF into my app. I'm then creating annotations using the onDraw method. The annotations appear within the app, but I now need to be able to save them to the original or a copy of the original PDF document. My understanding is that the annotations are just using canvas to draw over the PDF, rather than actually modifying the PDF. Any idea how to save them? Code of loading/creating annotations below.
        pdfView.fromAsset("TEST.pdf")
        .swipeHorizontal(true).pageSnap(true).autoSpacing(true).pageFling(true)
        .pageFitPolicy(FitPolicy.BOTH)
        .onDraw(object: OnDrawListener {
            override fun onLayerDrawn(
                canvas: Canvas,
                pageWidth: Float,
                pageHeight: Float,
                displayedPage: Int
            ) {
                val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvas.width, canvas.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
                val paint = Paint()
                paint.setColor(Color.RED)
                canvas.drawText("This is a test!", 50F, 50F, paint)
            }
        })
        .enableAnnotationRendering(true)
        .load()


Use a PDF library, such as iText, to read in, modify, and write out the PDF.

Or if you App is not open source and you don't want to pay for an iText License then try https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android

@Andrew thanks, yes our app is not open source and iText has been explored but is out of our price range. I've explored the documentation for PdfBox and my take away is I would need to render the PDF to a bitmap, save the user entered annotations, and then draw both using canvas - am I overcomplicating things?

I've not used PdfBox for annotations but I see two approaches, 1) Draw PDF to bitmap to display, when a user adds an annotation map it's location in the bitmap back to the PDF and then add the annotation to the PDF data structure and then just re-render the bitmap with the new data, this might be a bit slow. 2) Draw PDF to bitmap to display and then when a user adds an annotation draw on top of the PDF bitmap but store the type and location to be added to the PDF data structure when the user presses a save button.

@KJ do you have any references for other kotlin PDF editors that require a license and what the approximate cost of those licenses are?
Also, we have tossed around the idea of passing URI to open a third party app, like Adobe, to edit the PDF but that's kind of a last resort. To my knowledge, there is absolutely no way to display a third party app in our application by assigning it to a view, correct?

Add the build.gradle file:
implementation 'com.itextpdf:itext7-core:7.2.0'

Create a method to save the annotations to the PDF:
import com.itextpdf.kernel.colors.ColorConstants
import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.Rectangle
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph
import com.itextpdf.layout.property.TextAlignment
import java.io.FileOutputStream

fun savePdfWithAnnotations(inputPdfPath: String, outputPdfPath: String) {
    val pdfDocument = PdfDocument(PdfWriter(outputPdfPath))
    val document = Document(pdfDocument)

    // Read the original PDF
    val reader = com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader(inputPdfPath)
    val originalPdfDocument = PdfDocument(reader)
    val numberOfPages = originalPdfDocument.numberOfPages

    // Copy pages from the original PDF
    originalPdfDocument.copyPagesTo(1, numberOfPages, pdfDocument)

    // Add annotations (this example adds text to the first page)
    val canvas = pdfDocument.getPage(1).newContentStreamBefore()
    val red = ColorConstants.RED
    val fontSize = 12f
    val text = "This is a test!"

    // Define the annotation location and size
    val rect = Rectangle(50f, 750f, 200f, 20f)
    val paragraph = Paragraph(text)
        .setFontColor(red)
        .setFontSize(fontSize)
        .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT)

    document.showTextAligned(paragraph, 50f, 750f, 1, TextAlignment.LEFT, com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.AffineTransform(0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0), 0.0f)

    // Close documents
    document.close()
    originalPdfDocument.close()
    pdfDocument.close()
}

Call this method when you need to save the PDF with annotations:
val inputPdfPath = "path/to/TEST.pdf"
val outputPdfPath = "path/to/annotated_TEST.pdf"
savePdfWithAnnotations(inputPdfPath, outputPdfPath)


Thanks for the reply. We can't use iText due to their licensing policies.
